# How to prevent outlook to delete updates about events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, updates, calendar

My problem is that, at work, outlook 365 Pro Plus deletes e-mails regarding to the events at peoples accounts, who approved the meeting.

I have changed the setting: "delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding"

but this only prevents deleting the original invitation E-mail. If there is an update about it -for example an update in the explanation of the event-, it would go automatically into the deleted folder.

Funny enough, the people who actually wont go to the event or who did not respond to it, would receive the email.

Do you have a solution for this?

thank you!

Comment: Are you using Exchange Online account? I just directly test this issue on the OWA and meeting update arrive in Deleted Item folder, too. So this was moved to deleted folder by exchange server. However, this is not reproduced on Exchange 2013/2016 account.

Comment: I think I am using an Exchange Online account ( I am not pretty sure what that is but it is a work E-mail adress) and it is Office 365. I am not sure about the former versions.

Comment: I also tested with my Exchange Online account, and reproduced. But if I tested with Exchange server 2013 account, meeting update will stay in Inbox. I think this may be an issue with Exchange Online server because same behavior on OWA